# Error while trying to connect Java with database

Tags: java, database, javafx

I have class database where I tried to create database, tables and some function on tables.

This is part of main code in databasle class: (if you need something more, Im here!).

```
public class db {

public static db database = new db();

private static Connection conn = null;
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307";
private static String db_name = "csdz11";
private static String db_user = "root";
private static String db_pass = "";
```

This is error: (If you need whole message I will update answer, but I hope this will be enough for this case.)

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/csdz11
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at util.db.openConn(db.java:55)
at util.db.prikazBaze(db.java:160)
at zadatak1.Zadatak1.start(Zadatak1.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in Application start method
```

However, I made application, JavaFX inputs, but got that error while trying to run it, so, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error suggests that the MySQL-connector jar is not in your classpath. Include the jar

Comment: Thank you for answering, how I can include the jar? Throught netbeans options or?

Comment: You can include it in the IDE (Netbeans), however, you'll face a similar problem when running outside the IDE. Rather add it to you package-manager, like Maven, if you are using one so that it runs outside your IDE as well

Comment: LOL, that worked fine I succesfully added on user with javafx controls into database, and now got this errors: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Without seeing a lot of your code, it would be difficult to diagnose the problem

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the static method within DriverManager to determine what drivers are registered with the runtime.  Your runtime (outside of your IDE) may not have visibility/access to the MySQL driver.

DriverManager.getDrivers() returns an Enumeration, which you can iterate through (a print statement or log file entry) the properties of each that are available.  If it's not there, work upstream to make sure it's installed.

```
public class DBDrivers {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    DriverManager.drivers().forEach(driver -> System.out.println(driver));}
```